# Problem with Elasticsearch and getting results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a Elasticsearch in a dockercontainer, but I have problems getting results back.
My set up is like this:
In program.cs

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Elasticsearch")));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .DefaultIndex(ElasticSearchHelper.AddressesIndexName);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(client);
```

My indexer:

```
await _elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync(AddressesIndexName, ct: cancellationToken);
            if (!(await _elasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync(AddressesIndexName, ct: cancellationToken)).Exists)
            {
                var result = await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(AddressesIndexName, m =>
                 m.Map<Address>(d =>
                     d.AutoMap()
                     .Properties(
                         p => p
                         .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Street))
                         .Keyword(t => t.Name(n => n.AddressId))
                         .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.AddressId))
                     )
                 )
                , ct: cancellationToken);
            }
            int totalRows = 0;
            var addresses = await _dataContext.Addresses.Take(100).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            performContext.WriteLine($"Found {addresses.Count} addresses");
            if (addresses.Count > 0)
            {
                var bulkAllObservable = _elasticClient.BulkAll(addresses, b => b
                     .Index(AddressesIndexName)
                     .BackOffTime("30s")
                     .BackOffRetries(2)
                     .RefreshOnCompleted()
                     .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                     .Size(1000)
                )
                .Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), next =>
                {
                    totalRows = totalRows + next.Items.Count;
                    performContext.WriteLine(ConsoleTextColor.Green, "{totalRows} of {addresses.Count}");
                });
            }
```

My first query that does return results

```
var docs = _elasticClient.Search<Address>(b => b
            .Index(ElasticSearchHelper.AddressesIndexName)
       .Query(q => q
           .Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Street).Terms("skovvangen"))
               
           )
       );
```

My second query that doesn't work:

```
docs = _elasticClient.Search<Address>(b => b
            .Index(ElasticSearchHelper.AddressesIndexName)
       .Query(q => q
           .Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.AddressId).Terms("000021c5-e9ee-411d-b2d8-ec9161780ccd"))

           )
       );
```

The first query returns a result but the second does not no matter what I do.
I am guess it is because I haven't set up the indexing correctly.
I am new to Elasticsearch, so I really need some pointers to what I am doing wrong.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: can you please put index mapping from ES. you can use `GET indexname` command to get it.

Comment: You map the AddressId twice: field.Keyword(t => t.Name(n => n.AddressId))
                         .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.AddressId))

text => could match case unsensitive ect (see doc for more information)
Keyword => could be only match as a key (case sensitive, exact words)